# Set a time limit to an oracle query

Tags: php, oracle, timeout, oci8

I need to interrupt the execution of an oracle query if it is taking more than 10 seconds, and give user a message informing him about execution timeout.
I googled a lot but i didn't find anything useful. 
Is there any way to set a time limit to oci_execute

Comment: I need to do it in PHP side because i don't have any chance to manage DB configurations.

Answer (score 2):

A profile can be used but is a little harsh. A better solution is to use Oracle Resource Manager. Setup a resource manager plan, assign resource consumer groups, decide how a session gets assigned to a resource consumer group and off you go.
You can even make it refuse to start a query when the estimated runtime exceeds the allowed runtime.
Also check http://ronr.blogspot.com/2009/06/howto-configure-resource-manager-using.html

Comment: I need to do it in PHP side because i don't have any chance to manage DB configurations.

Comment: In that case you need to be able to send a cancel message when your wait time expires. In PRO*c this is easy (well, need a little oci to set it up). In PHP ....  I don't know about that. If you can send a ctrl-C to the running connection it could work.

Comment: How about http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-cancel.php You will have to write your own timer.

Comment: Yes but how???? The execution of the code stops after oci_execute until it finish. Where can I intorduce a execution time  check?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a php scripter. Can you set and catch events in php? If so, set a timer event and when you catch such an event, send the cancel action. If your oci_execute returns, clear the timer event. Resource manager is a lot easier. Talk to the dba on site and explain.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Oracle profiles are useful in your case:
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/profile.html

Comment: I need to do it in PHP side because i don't have any chance to manage DB configurations.